# Ignore hidden files with php

Tags: php, arrays, opendir

I am trying to scan a folder of images, however I keep seeing the ._ files the mac created

I am using this code:

```
   <?php
if ($handle = opendir('assets/automotive')) {
    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..','._' );
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( !in_array($file,$ignore)) {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Any ideas as to why? I created a ignore array that covers it.

**Update: Still shows both.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to ignore any file that *begins* with a dot (.) and not just the filename.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('assets/automotive')) {
    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..','._' );
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file,$ignore) and substr($file, 0, 1) != '.') {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yup that's the trick, thank you! I will mark it accepted when it lets me

Comment: Given that we know `$file` is a non-empty string, `substr($file, 0, 1)` is a needlessly verbose way of writing `$file[0]`. The redundancy of having the `$ignore` array include dotfiles despite them being covered by the other condition is also ugly.

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` [takes two parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php): the thing you want to find, and the array to search in.
You want:

```
if ( !in_array($file, $ignore))
```

Comment: I added it, and still shows both types

Comment: I ran similar code and it works properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), but the next questions is: "is *what* in_array".

in_array needs a second parameter, in this case `$file`, to look for. You'll need:

```
in_array($file,$ignore);
```